# Trying to create a function, and then filtering a sequence by "not that function" in F#

Tags: f#

My data is a SEQUENCE of:

`[(40,"TX");(48,"MO");(15,"TX");(78,"TN");(41,"VT")]`

My code is as follows:

```
type Csvfile = CsvProvider<somefile>
let data = Csvfile.GetSample().Rows

let nullid row = 
    row.Id = 15

let otherid row =
    row.Id= 40

let iddata = 
   data
   |> Seq.filter (not nullid)
   |> Seq.filter (not otherid)
```

I create the functions.

Then I want to call the "not" of those functions to filter them out of a sequence.

But the issue is that I am getting errors for "row.Id" in the first two functions, because you can only do that with a type.

How do I solve this problem so I can accomplish this successfully.

My result should be a SEQUENCE of:

`[(48,"MO);(78,"TN");(41,"VT")]`

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: what else should I add? this is essentially everything

Comment: I cannot copy, paste and run your code. Please make it easy for us to answer. The minimal part should mean that I don't need to worry about a CSV file - I assume that isn't causing the problem. So please give us sensible input data, your rules, and your expected outcome.

Comment: @Enigmativity my question has been updated

Comment: I would still like to see data that is in valid F# code rather than need to muck around with CSV files.

Comment: When I copy, paste, and run your code I get "The type 'CsvProvider' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following: SqlProvider (using external F# compiler)".

Comment: you can add a type annotation or use SRTP. Also, you should delimit items with `;` between the tuples, not ,.

Comment: Please look at the two examples, one using SRTP, the other a type annotation. I also structured the post so it is closer to an MCVE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `>>` operator to compose the two functions:

```
let iddata = 
   data
   |> Seq.filter (nullid >> not)
   |> Seq.filter  (othered >> not)
```

See [Function Composition and Pipelining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/index#function-composition-and-pipelining).

Or you can make it more explicit:

```
let iddata = 
   data
   |> Seq.filter (fun x -> not (nullid x))
   |> Seq.filter  (fun x -> not (othered x))
```

You can see that in action:

```
let input = [|1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10|];;
let is3 value =
    value = 3;;

input |> Seq.filter (fun x -> not (is3 x));;
input |> Seq.filter (not >> is3);;
```

They both print `val it : seq<int> = seq [1; 2; 4; 5; ...]`

Comment: The crucial aspect, is that I need to be able to call a row from the CSV. For example "row.Id".

Comment: I think the OP's problem is that he can't access the `Id` property, because of course a generic type cannot have this property. Only specific types (constrained to have the Id property can have it), or you need to use a type annotation to make clear that the function operates on that type only and it's not generic.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below what an MCVE might look in your case, for an fsx file you can reference the `Fsharp.Data` dll with `#r`, for a compiled project just reference the dll an open it.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r @"..\..\SO2018\packages\FSharp.Data\lib\net45\FSharp.Data.dll"
#endif

open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let datafile = @"C:\tmp\data.csv"
type CsvFile = CsvProvider<datafile>
let data = CsvFile.GetSample().Rows
```

In the end this is what you want to achieve:

```
data
|> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.Id <> 15)
|> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.Id <> 40)
//val it : seq<CsvProvider<...>.Row> = seq [(48, "MO"); (78, "TN"); (41, "VT")]
```

One way to do this is with [SRTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters), as they allow a way to do structural typing, where the type depends on its shape, for example in this case having the `Id` property. If you want you can define helper function for the two numbers 15 and 40, and use that in your filter, just like in the second example. However SRTP syntax is a bit strange, and it's designed for a use case where you need to apply a function to different types that have some similarity (basically like interfaces).

```
let inline getId row =
    (^T : (member Id :  int) row)

data
|> Seq.filter (fun x -> (getId x <> 15 ))
|> Seq.filter (fun x -> (getId x <> 40))
//val it : seq<CsvProvider<...>.Row> = seq [(48, "MO"); (78, "TN"); (41, "VT")]
```

Now back to your original post, as you correctly point out your function will show an error, as you define it to be generic, but it needs to operate on a specific Csv row type (that has the Id property). This is very easy to fix, just add a type annotation to the `row` parameter. In this case your type is `CsvFile.Row`, and since CsvFile.Row has the Id property we can access that in the function. Now this function returns a Boolean. You could make it return the actual row as well.

```
let nullid (row: CsvFile.Row)  =
    row.Id = 15


let otherid (row: CsvFile.Row) =
    row.Id = 40
```

Then what is left is applying this inside a `Seq.filter` and negating it:

```
let iddata = 
    data 
    |> Seq.filter (not << nullid) 
    |> Seq.filter (not << otherid)
    |> Seq.toList
//val iddata : CsvProvider<...>.Row list = [(48, "MO"); (78, "TN"); (41, "VT")]
```